# I want to send a mail from a PDF depending on check boxes

Tags: javascript, email, pdf

In a PDF (a form) I have inserted a button "send a mail" and I want the form to be sent to diffent mail adress depending on the previous check boxes.

To be practical :
There is a questio "Size of the company" with 2 boxes that can be checked. Depending on the one checked, the mail is sent to different addresses.

I think it must be done with a Javascript code in the "Parameters" of the button, but  dont know how to code this..

Thank you very much

Florian

Answer (score 0):

append a value to your checkboxes and when form is submitted, different POST data is retrieved, and run an if else loop to fire your phpmailer to different addresses